Is my differentiation of these words correct: engender, lead to, result in, bring about?
First, let's ignore the fact that lead to implies there are several steps between the cause and the outcome.
After some research, this is my attempt to differentiate these words:
engender: making a feeling or situation exist
 result in, bring about: making a situation exist (not feelings)
lead to: making a feeling, situation, or other things (?) exist
According to dictionary definitions, one might be inclined to say that lead to is used in a very wide range of situations, while there are some restrictions to the other three as described above. However, I somehow feel that result in and bring about can be used interchangeably with lead to (again, excluding situations where speakers want to imply that there are steps/stages between the cause and the outcome) because I've heard them used with feelings before, for example "result in unhappiness".
What do you think?

"However, I somehow feel that result in and bring about can be used interchangeably with lead to" Why do you feel that?

I uggest you look up actual utterances, not just definitions. That said, I don't understand how this is anything other than a teach-onself vocabulary exercise.

@StuartF Sorry, I've clarified that in my post.

@Lambie This is a question related to word-choice. Isn't it one of the tags on this site?

I did check the utterances, however, it's still pretty confusing to me because in those examples, these words all seem to mean the same thing.

You ask a lot of questions re related words. And in my experience of teaching/learning languages, it's best to find sentences where they are used, not just dictionary definitions.

I understand, and I always do that before asking questions actually. But it's not as easy as it may sound. If reading examples could always enable us to distinguish words, there wouldn't be this many word-choice questions here from all kinds of users.

Engender is derived from a word meaning beget (become the father of), so it has the sense of actually creating something.
The other expressions seem to me to have more of a sense of 'setting off a chain of circumstances which result in something happening'. You say you want to exclude the possibility of there being several stages, so we could call it 'causing a situation in which something is very likely to happen'.

Thank you, so "lead to, bring to, result in" can be used interchangeably?

@AnIELTSLearner It's bring about, not bring to. Big difference.

Oh my bad. I don't know why I typed "bring to".

Pretty much interchangeably, yes.
